# jquery autocomplete not showing result on dropdown list, only blanks row

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

starting saying that I approached jquery and ajax for the first time and only for the purpose of developing a little site to help the productivity of my work society.
I've been here looking everywhere for an answer but it seems no one is having my same problem.
being sorry for my poor English, I'm going to show you the code I'm using, hoping someone could help.

here php.

```
<?php 
try {
    $dbh = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;port=33000;dbname=magazinoacc", 'root', 'administrator');
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Errore: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
// var_dump($_POST);exit;
if (! isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $q="%";
} else {
    $q=$_GET['term']."%";
}
$sql="  SELECT *
        FROM pv
        WHERE Cliente like :q;";
$stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindparam(':q',$q);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $stringa = [];
foreach($rows as $row){
    $stringa[] = array(
        'cliente' => $row['Cliente'],
        'localita' => $row['Località'],
        'indirizzo' => $row['Indirizzo'],
    );
    // $stringa.=sprintf('{cliente :" %s" localita" : "%s" indirizzo: "%s"},', $row['Cliente'], $row['Località'], $row['Indirizzo']);
}
// echo '['.substr($stringa,0,-1).']';
echo json_encode($stringa)
?>
```

here the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#cliente").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function(request, response) { 
                $.ajax({
                    url:"ajax.php",
                    data:  {
                        mode : "ajax",
                        term : request.term,
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data)     {

                        response(data);
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
           },
           select:  function(e, ui) {
                $('#localita').val(ui.item.localita);
                $('#indirizzo').val(ui.item.indirizzo);

            }
        });
});
```

and here html

```
<table>
<form method="post">
    <tr>
        <td class="sx">value: </td>
        <td class="dx"><input type="text" size="50"  name="cliente" id="cliente">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sx">label: </td>
        <td class="dx"><input type="text" size="50"  name="localita" id="localita">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sx">label: </td>
        <td class="dx"><input type="text" size="50"  name="indirizzo" id="indirizzo">
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

the result is this:
[image of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAPdc.jpg)

(cannot show more details)
as you can see the script return the right JSON array but, on the drop-down list, I cannot see anything, only black rows that contain the right result.
why are they blank?

thanks for any suggestion

Comment: What if you use this : https://pastebin.com/RUMYzJNT ?

Comment: It works if json sent is in format - [{"value":"america"},{"value":"argentina"}]

Comment: @KarloKokkak if u see the image, returned value is exactly like that
[{"cliente" : ".....", "localita" : "....", "indirizzo" : "....."}, ....]
in fact I'm able to populate other fields with the right result
if i use only source: 'ajax.php' the result is the same

Comment: It is not. They are named - `cliente`, `localita` and `indirizzo`. They're supposed to be labaled `"value:"` instead.

Comment: is that because autocomplete cannot recognize label as cliente?

Comment: It cannot recognize cliente as label or value.

Comment: i've tryied also this 
https://pastebin.com/CmMKx1gP
but does not worsk

Comment: That won't work. Try my suggestion. :)

Comment: are you suggesting to change cliente, localita and indirizzo directly on my php file?
keep in mind I don't know ajax and jscript, i'm adapting existing code from internet

Comment: Are you including the latest jquery.js file?

Comment: i'm including this
https://pastebin.com/9F9BFf4m

Comment: Your php file is called ajax.php right?

Comment: yes ajax.php is the php filest that search on the database

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're not passing the correct Json output. And your autocomplete js script is incorrectly coded.

Try the below codes. See if they work.

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
try {
    $dbh = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;port=33000;dbname=magazinoacc", 'root', 'administrator');
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Errore: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
// var_dump($_POST);exit;
if (! isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $q="%";
} else {
    $q=$_GET['term']."%";
}
$sql="  SELECT *
        FROM pv
        WHERE Cliente like :q;";
$stmt=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindparam(':q',$q);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $stringa = [];
foreach($rows as $row){
    $stringa[] = array(
        'label' => $row['Cliente'],
        'value' => $row['Cliente']
    );
    // $stringa.=sprintf('{cliente :" %s" localita" : "%s" indirizzo: "%s"},', $row['Cliente'], $row['Località'], $row['Indirizzo']);
}
// echo '['.substr($stringa,0,-1).']';
echo json_encode($stringa)
?>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#cliente").autocomplete({
            source: 'ajax.php'
        });

        $("#localita").autocomplete({
            source: 'ajax.php?from=localita'
        });

         $("#indirizzo").autocomplete({
            source: 'ajax.php?from=indirizzo'
        });
});
```

Comment: it doesn't works
instead
adding this https://pastebin.com/trWB2w8H to my code it works on showing dropdown but, fail on autocomplete

Comment: Updated the PHP file. Test again.

Comment: I'll try later but, seems you are returning only Cliente but I need to show also "localita" and "indirizzo".

Comment: Let me know if the above works then let's move to the other two.

Comment: it oviusly work, as you are passing only one value...
I'm trying to pass 3 or more value to populate 3 or more fields...
This -> https://pastebin.com/trWB2w8H
work on drop down list, but cannot populated fields, probably due tu my ignorance on manipulate the data from response...

Answer (score 0):

After some try I've managed to resolve the problem, using this script.
It obviusly could be more simplified, or optimized, but I think i should be happy ^^

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#cliente").autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function(request, response) { 
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    data:  {
                        mode : "ajax",
                        term : request.term,
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                        response($.map(data, function (oggetto) {
                             return oggetto.cliente + "|" + oggetto.localita + "|" + oggetto.indirizzo ;
                         }))
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
           },
           focus: function(event, ui) {
              var stringasplit=ui.item.value.split("|");
               var cliente=stringasplit[0];
               var localita=stringasplit[1];
               var indirizzo=stringasplit[2];
              event.preventDefault();
                $('#cliente').val(cliente);
                $('#localita').val(localita);
                $('#indirizzo').val(indirizzo);
                console.log(ui.item.value);
            },
          select:  function(event, ui) {
              var stringasplit=ui.item.value.split("|");
               var cliente=stringasplit[0];
               var localita=stringasplit[1];
               var indirizzo=stringasplit[2];
              event.preventDefault();
                $('#cliente').val(cliente);
                $('#localita').val(localita);
                $('#indirizzo').val(indirizzo);
                console.log(ui.item.value);
            },
        });
});
```